# Finding out the file name in a FileUploadHandler

Tags: django

I am rolling my own fileupload handler in django and would like to know the file name. I am supporting more than one file format and want to do different processing in the `receive_data_chunk` method depending on which file format the uploaded file has. I thought I would be pragmatic and just judge file format based on file ending but I can't figure out how to get hold of the file name. If I try to extract the file name with something like the following code (before that method is called):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = re.compile('^.*\.sdf$', re.IGNORECASE)
        if ( p.search(request.FILES['filecontent'].name) ) :
            self.sdf = True
        else:
            self.sdf = False
```

It seems I never reach the `receive_data_chunk` method. I presume the call to `request.FILES` trigger the loading somehow and then it's already done? How can I do different processing based on file ending in my `receive_data_chunk` method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
data=request.POST.copy()
```

and then working on the copy? I have used this for other things but may work in this case as well.

Comment: Hm, interesting, does that mean I get a full copy of the entire thing? What does that mean if I am uploading a file of say, uhm, 3 GB?

Comment: That's a great question! I don't think that any of the files that I was involved with were greater than a few MB max.